# CSRF token is refreshing with every page, and expriring instantly

Tags: laravel

This is happening after we migrated to a new server, same domain different subdomain

My env file:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.thecorrectdomainhere.ca  
SESSION_DRIVER=file  
SESSION_LIFETIME=120  
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false  (the new server doesn't have SSL set up yet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Session domain should be the same as the sub-domain `ex : x.thecorrectdomainhere.ca`

Comment: even though I want it to work on multiple subdomains? they've got 2 subdomains running out of the same folder, so we can keep it up during the migration

Comment: use the * flag..... *..thecorrectdomainhere.ca

Answer (score 0):

it was Chrome blocking cookies since we didn't have SSH set up yet

We had to change samesite from none to lax